# Receiving segmentation fault on various commands Centos 5.8

Tags: php, centos5, segmentation-fault

I have a server running CentOs 5.8.  I installed New Relic yesterday.

From 9am this morning the following commands give me Segmentation Fault:

- wget
- yum
- rpm

I can still access Midnight Commander, and our application is also running fine.

I have PHP 5.3.1 installed and it's also a live application server.

--

Since my previous comment I have cloned my server to experiment and now I am getting the message below. It looks liek this was updated yesterday. any ideas how I can repair this?

Many thanks

There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

/usr/lib64/librpmbuild-4.4.so: invalid ELF header

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Feb 22 2012, 16:05:45)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq

Answer (score 0):

That's part of the `rpm-libs` package.  I can see this affecting rpm and yum, but not wget, so it's likely other files are also corrupt, so cherry picking individual library files from elsewhere might be more hassle than it's worth, compared to restoring from backup.

Disk issue?  Run `fsck`?

Comment: Thanks.  To restore from a backup, can I just copy system files over?  It's a transactional system.  I suppose I could backup the DB, restore to a point from last week and then update the DB.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Hmm, that should be OK: basically, restore to any good point and roll your DB forward.

Answer (score 0):

Check for unauthorized logins.  I've seen this on systems where someone gains root access (usually through insecure root logins) and in an attempt to install botnet software on there, they also overwrite MANY popular programs with version compiled for a different kernels.  wget, vi, tail, less, grep, etc.

In the cases that I've seen in the past, they're usually dropping Linux binaries onto a SCO.  Since you're already on Linux, that seems less likely, but I would certainly look into it.